# Extent HTML Report not saving in correct location

Tags: java, appium, extentreports

I am trying to save an Extent report into a folder on my C:/drive. Currently it is just saving the report into the project folder.

I've tried different paths and making sure I give access to the java folder.

This is the class where the reporter gets attached and also the file path gets set.

```
class ExtentManager {

    private static ExtentReports extent;
    private static String fileName = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm").format(new Date());

    static ExtentReports getInstance() {
        if (extent == null) {
            extent = createInstance("Testing " + fileName + ".html");

            System.out.println("JUST CREATED A NEW EXTENT");
        }

        return extent;
    }

    private static ExtentReports createInstance(String fileName) {
        ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(fileName);
        htmlReporter.config().setTestViewChartLocation(ChartLocation.BOTTOM);
        htmlReporter.config().setChartVisibilityOnOpen(true);
        htmlReporter.config().setTheme(Theme.DARK);
        htmlReporter.config().setDocumentTitle(fileName);
        htmlReporter.config().setEncoding("utf-8");
        htmlReporter.config().setReportName(fileName);
        htmlReporter.config().setFilePath(System.getProperty("user.home") + ("/Documents/ExtentReport/HTMLReports"));

        ExtentReports extent = new ExtentReports();
        extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter);

        return extent;
    }
}
```

I expect it to save the report into my documents. The actual result is the report gets saved in the project folder.

Comment: Why would you expect it to save the file in the documents folder when you're not specifying -any- folder?  If you don't specify a folder, it uses the project folder.

Comment: May be you are missing "/" at the end of the path. It has to be "..../ExtentReport/HTMLReports/"

Comment: Instead of giving filename in `ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(fileName);`, try giving the exact path where you want to save the report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correction in yours:

```
  private static String fileName = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm").format(new Date());
  String reportLocation = "C:/ReportFolder/" + "Testing " + fileName + ".html";

  static ExtentReports getInstance() {
    if (extent == null) {
        extent = createInstance(reportLocation);
        System.out.println("JUST CREATED A NEW EXTENT");
    }
```